# Is it possible to distribute binary ios framework using carthage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage

Please bear with me because I spent considerable amount of time on this. I am also relatively a beginner with swift and iOS.

**What I did**
- built a framework using cocoa touch
- clean, build and it succeeds without a problem.
- made the scheme shared
- did `carthage build --no-skip-current`
- did `carthage archive`
- copied only the zip file to a fresh new directory and uploaded with release in git.
- In a different project tried to pull the framework using carthage

and I get the error `Dependency "xxx-ios" has no shared framework schemes`  then I copied the scheme directly and pushed it in the git along the zip. nothing. Tried without the zip together with the scheme. nothing.

Then I created a fresh framework and I did `carthage build --no-skip-current` and I uploaded the whole thing in the project folder to git. That pulls properly with carthage. Then I removed some part of that folder so that the scheme inside .xcodeproj and the carthage build folder remain, then I get a different error. At this point it got me thinking if carthage does support binary framework distribution.

In my company, they want it so that I don't expose the code - so I am trying to distribute built binary of the framework.

I would really appreciate any help or guides of what different things I could try to single out the problem. Thanks.

**Edit**
someone had almost exactly the same issue as mine in their issues [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1109) but a couple of conversations later it is closed without a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a `github` dependency in your `Cartfile` and attaching a binary of your framework to the GitHub Release. But you don't have any code in the repository, so Carthage is complaining because it can't actually build it.

That's as designed—Carthage doesn't support distributing binary-only frameworks that way. Binaries attached to GitHub Releases are only meant as a way to speed up builds.

However, Carthage does have a mechanism for binary-only dependencies: [`binary` dependencies](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#binary-only-frameworks).

Comment: would have been nice tho, if this binary feature has the ability to clone from git.